# best_score_ vs. accuracy_score_ vs. AUROC performance score for classification models (binary)

Tags: binary, classification

I have these three metrics for my classification task. Can someone tells me in plain English, what the differences are, which one(s) to use and when to utilize them?

Thank you

```
for name, model in fitted_models.items():
    print(name, model.best_score_)
```

#### l1

0.8493863035326624

#### l2

0.8493863035326624

#### rf

0.9796513913558318

#### gb

0.9752980461811722

///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
for name, model in fitted_models.items():
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print(name, accuracy_score(y_test, pred))
```

#### l1

0.8603411513859275

#### l2

0.8603411513859275

#### rf

0.9790334044065387

#### gb

0.9758351101634684

///////////////////////////////////////////////

```
for name, model in fitted_models.items():
    pred = model.predict_proba(X_test)
    pred = [p[1] for p in pred]
    print(name, roc_auc_score(y_test, pred))
```

#### l1

0.9015388373737675

#### l2

0.9015381433597084

#### rf

0.9915194952019338

#### gb

0.988678201643009

Answer (score 0):

1.frist thing :

```
model.best_score_
```

return to you accuracy on **train data** but two others in this question works with **test data**

2.**model.best_score_**  & **accuracy_score(y_test, pred)** return to you mean accuracy for all classes with :

```
accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tp + fp + fn + tn)
```

but  **roc_auc_score(y_test, pred)** calculate auc with probability perdicts separate for each class and Of course with area under the ROC curve

3.accuracy on train data not good metrics parameter and roc auc is better than accuracy when we can use **predict_proba()**

4.at the end **Precision and recall** is better parameters than **accuracy** and we must choose wisely between the two them based on our need

i offer you **classification_report** this method return to you all parameters for each class and average them :

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y_test))
```